# Pipenv install: No module named "..."

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pipenv

This works fine:

```
pipenv install
pipenv shell
pip freeze
```

I can see my dependencies installed.

But! Then I start a notebook:

> pipenv run jupyter notebook

From here I can no longer import all modules:

> "No module named ..."

The only way I found to remedy it, is to add the virtual env to the path:

> add /Users/me/.virtualenvs/my-project-sSvqGt-H/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

```
// all paths before adding virtualenv
['/Users/me/Desktop/projects/this-project/maker/examples',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/me/.ipython']
```

What is going on here? Why is my Notebook running in the Pipenv not able to access the virtualenv site packages without additional paths?